# How to calculate surface out of GPS points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have uploaded several squares (which consist out of 4 GPS points, not connected). I  need the total surface of the squares.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Do I create polygons and than calculate the surface?

Comment: Never used GPS points so cannot confirm this but my guess would be for you to create polygons (use something like **Convert points to lines** from SAGA) and then use the Field Calculator to create a new column. Use `$area` in the expression to obtain the area for each square, then manually add them. I may be completely wrong, in which case I hope others can provide a definitive answer.